# Type hint current class inside __init__

Tags: python, python-typing

Let's imagine I have a class:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next_item=None):
        self.value: int = value
        self.next_item: Node = next_item
```

Is it possible to "type hint" all `__init__` params? Something like this:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self: Self, value: int = None, next_item: Node = None):
        self.value: int = value
        self.next_item: Node = next_item
```

`next_item`, as we can see, can't refer to `Node`, because it doesn't yet exist. Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

add line `from __future__ import annotations` in import and this will work with second option